# Selecting an element with two selectors

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to select elements on a class ,put them on an array. For each element in that class I want to select the "a" Tag and then I want to make a listener for each element, but this is a mess that seems impossible for me in JS. Heres the code I have so far.

```
var elemento = new Array();
var y=document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails");

for (var i=0; i < y.length; i++) {
    elemento = ( y[i].getElementsByTagName("a"));
    elemento[0].addEventListener('click', function(){alert("jo")}, false);
}
```

This works for the first element but not for the rest, and yes, elemento is `[0]` because there's no more "a" tags inside each thumbnail.

Comment: I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/): `$('.thumbnails a').click(function() { ... })`

Comment: Don't use a big library like jQuery for these super easy little tasks.

Comment: would please show html ? I believe your code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

One short way for modern browsers is to use CSS selectors in [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnails a');
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() { ... }, false);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AApw2/

Answer (score 1):

While `.querySelectorAll` is a good solution, it's important to understand how this would be handled without it.

What you simply need is an inner loop to loop over the current set of `a` elements held by the `elemento` variable.

```
var elemento;
var y = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails");
var handler = function(){alert("jo")};

for (var i=0; i < y.length; i++) {
    elemento = y[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var j = 0; j < elemento.length; j++) {
        elemento[j].addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    }
}
```

Notice that I use a different counter `j` for the inner loop since `i` is already in use.

Notice also that I moved the handler function to a variable outside the loop. This makes all the elements use the same function object, which is more efficient.

---

*Side note:*

You may also want to create some helper methods that will shorten the long method names, and convert them to Arrays. This allows you to use Array methods like `.forEach()`.

```
var _slice = Function.call.bind([].slice);

function byClass(ctx, clss) {
    if (typeof ctx === "string") {
        clss = ctx;
        ctx = document;
    }
    return _slice(ctx.getElementsByClassName(clss));
}
function byTag(ctx, tag) {
    if (typeof ctx === "string") {
        tag = ctx;
        ctx = document;
    }
    return _slice(ctx.getElementsByTagName(tag));
}
```

---

That reduces your code to this:

```
var handler = function(){alert("jo")};

byClass("thumbnails").forEach(function(thumb) {
    byTag(thumb, "a").forEach(function(a) {
        a.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    });
});
```

Comment: I doubt that `NodeList` has `Array.prototype.forEach` method available. You should better convert it to the pure array with `Array.prototype.slice` first.

Comment: @VisioN: Yeah, I mentioned the Array conversion in the text, but forgot to add it to the code. I'll update. Thanks.

Comment: @user3129738: I didn't fully implement the code that I described. It's now fixed to show the full implementation.